French Rom-Com about a musician
It's a French film about a musician and his father-in-law/ his girlfriend's father. I remember that it starts with the protagonist performing a song he wrote. The lyrics of the song spell out the words "Je t'aime" (J-E-T-'-A-I-M-E). After his performance he meets a girl (I believe her name was Lola) and later they become a couple.
I can't remember much after that, but I think he meets her parents and becomes friends with her father but the girl breaks up with him. I can also recall that a pop singer steals the lyrics to his song, but he writes another one with the girl's name in it,and after that they get back together.
I guess the movie came out in the early 2010, but I'm not sure.

This movie is called Les Gamins.
Here is the synopsis from Wikipedia FR translated to English :

Thomas is a young man who dreams of a career in music. Gilbert is the future father-in-law of Thomas, married to Suzanne for 30 years and father of Lola, the bride of Thomas. Tired of his boring life as a couple, Gilbert decided one day to go and resume his life, taking Thomas with him to avoid sinking into the same 
  routine. This new life of kids will allow them to live life in a new light, without the worries of everyday life, but also to create others.

You can listen to Je t'aime extracted from the original sound track and performed by Max Boublil (who plays the role of Thomas).

Kindly explain how it matched description
